# Executing a python script on its own

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a small code to be able to open up a game and log me in. I created this using python 34. I am pretty new to python and the whole coding world so I'm not sure if what I want to do is possible. I created this code so that I can run it by a single click and it will do as the code says, so far I was only able to make it work by running it through cmd. I'm looking into a way so that I can run it by opening up a file that would be on my desktop.

This is the code:

```
import pyautogui
import time

#print(pyautogui.position())

pyautogui.click(x=326, y=883)
time.sleep(6)

pyautogui.click(x=767, y=75)
time.sleep(6)

pyautogui.click(x=361, y=414)
pyautogui.typewrite("*********") #Password to the login 

pyautogui.click(x=528, y=453)
```

If anyone could help me, I would appreciate it a lot and thank you in advance.

Comment: First of all, do you mean `python 27` (instead of `python 37`)? Secondly, what happens when you double-click on your `.py` file right now?

Comment: "python 37" - unless you're from the future, that can't be the right version.

Comment: Sorry I meant 34. Apologies

Answer (score 0):

I think what are you're looking for is pyinstaller(Making your .py, executable .exe)
Go here: http://www.pyinstaller.org/
Choose your version and pip install it.
If you don't know how to install it, open cmd, navigate to your folder.
and type `pip install pyinstaller`.

Edited: cx_Freeze is what you're looking for I believe
http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/ Installing goes same way,

```
pip install cx_Freeze
```

Comment: As far as I understand, you aren't able to use pyinstaller with python 34 as there are modules which are not compatible. I am using 'pyautogui' which I think will not work.

Comment: Oh, I though he meant 2.7 when it was written as 3.7 :)

Comment: Edited, check now.

Comment: You only need to make a .py file executable if you want to use it on a system without python installed.

Comment: As far as I understand he wants to execute he's game, so he run it. :)